# Do I ask question to explain the given snippet here?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am having some code snippets with me. I want clear explanations about that snippets. Shall I ask these kind of questions in this Programming Puzzle community? If not where do I ask such questions?

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to clarify on meta first! This demonstrates the biggest reason why I think we should [change our name](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5759/20260) to something without "programming puzzles". It makes total sense that a new user who is puzzled about some programming might post their question here. We get such requests for help often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you should not ask this kind of a question here.
Our community is about programming competitions.
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is probably the right place for your question (but make sure you read their [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, it will help you to get better answers).